# How to post json data with Rest API

Tags: ruby, json, rest

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
postData = Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse('http://localhost/restapi/index.php/api/posts'), 
                           {'id'=>9,'firstname'=>"test","lastname"=>"test"})
puts postData.body
```

How can I send data in JSON form?

```
@toSend = {"id" =>5,"firstname" => "anurag","lastname" => "arya"}
```

I also tried this but it did not work:

```
@toSend.to_json
```

Example:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
require 'json'

url = "http://localhost/restapi/index.php/api/posts"
uri = URI.parse(url)
data = {"id"=>11,                                          
              "firstname"=>"PWD","lastname"=>"last"}     

headers = {'Content-Type' =>'application/json',               
                     'Accept-Encoding'=> "gzip,deflate",
                     'Accept' => "application/json"}

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host,uri.port)   # Creates a http object
#http.use_ssl = true                                          # When using https
#http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
response = http.post(uri.path,data.to_json,headers)
puts response.code
puts response.body
```

Comment: If possible, avoid using bold all-caps in your questions. It doesn't help to be yelling all the time.

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Comment: it solved now by using post_form.

Comment: ok @tadman , i will take care of it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
postData=Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse('http://localhost/oecprashant/yiiIndex.php/api/rubyREST'), 
                           {'data'=>jsonData})
```

Comment: sending data in this way using post_form

Comment: No, this does not submit `jsonData` as the raw request body, but instead submits a urlencoded request with a single key-value pair `data=<encoded-JSON-string>`.